# Slow synchronization when sending and receiving in MPI application

Tags: c, mpi

[EDIT: I have started checking network issues since comments suggests this is more likely the problem than incorrect use of MPI]

I have attempted to use MPI to distribute a MonteCarlo simulation in an office LAN. Our small cluster have 4 nodes (Windows 10) and one shared networkfolder, and uses Microsoft MPI (latest version). The experiment have been rather successful with one annoying problem. The first send/receive takes a long time to complete, often more than 60 seconds. However, once the first send/receive has completed, all the following (thousands) send/receive goes fast.

We turned of the firewalls but it did not make a difference. Also, it is only between some pairs of nodes that this initial lag is a problem.

I have a small program (helloMPI.exe) that runs into the same problem. The code is as follows:

```
// Get the number of processes
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
int size = world_size;

// Get the rank of the process
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
int rank = world_rank;

if (rank == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Send 1 to 0 from 1" << std::endl;
    int s = 1;
    MPI_Send(&s, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << "Send !!" << std::endl;
}

if (rank == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Receive from " << 1 << std::endl;
    int number = 5555;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    std::cout << "Received " << number << std::endl;
}

// Finalize the MPI environment.
MPI_Finalize();
```

}

When I run my helloMPI.exe using:

**mpiexec -hosts 2 localhost 1 10.241.42.117 1 -p 8677 -path "\my_shared_folder\on_the_network" helloMPI.exe**

That is, I have two smpd.exe on two nodes. I initially get the output:

**Receive from 1

Send 1 to 0 from 1**

and then after about 60 seconds the output is:

**Receive from 1

Send 1 to 0 from 1

Received 1

Send !!**

I have tried the non-blocking version of the send/recieve functions, but it does not seem to make a difference. We are a bit stuck on this problem, I am still a bit suspicious about the firewalls, they can be rather intrusive and I am considering uninstalling them to see if it makes a difference. But I am starting to think we are missing something basic. Anyone have any ideas, or maybe have seen this problem before?

When I run mpiexec, and two smpd.exe on two nodes, with -d 3 I get the following output:

PS C:> mpiexec -d 3 -hosts 2 localhost 1 10.241.42.117 1 -p 8677 -path "\my_shared_folder\on_the_network" helloMPI.exe

[00:8504] host tree:

[00:8504]  host: localhost, parent: 0, id: 1

[00:8504]  host: 10.241.42.117, parent: 1, id: 2

[00:8504] mpiexec started smpd manager listening on port 63004

[00:8504] using spn msmpi/localhost to contact server

[00:8504] SYS-LT-GLH9K13 posting a re-connect to localhost:63006 in left child context.

[00:8504] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[00:8504] Authorization completed.

[00:8504] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[00:8504] creating connect command for left node

[00:8504] creating connect command to '10.241.42.117'

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_CONNECT to left child, src=0, dest=1.

[00:8504] host 10.241.42.117 is not connected yet

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_CONNECT result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_CONNECT result will be handled locally

[00:8504] successful connect to 10.241.42.117.

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_COLLECT to left child, src=0, dest=1.

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_COLLECT to left child, src=0, dest=2.

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_COLLECT result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_COLLECT result will be handled locally

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_COLLECT result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_COLLECT result will be handled locally

[00:8504] Finished collecting hardware summary.

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_STARTDBS to left child, src=0, dest=1.

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_STARTDBS result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_STARTDBS result will be handled locally

[00:8504] start_dbs succeeded, kvs_name: '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c', domain_name: 'f3d4b096-ec59-4893-b18d-dc9361b19a16'

[00:8504] creating a process group of size 2 on node 0 called 09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[00:8504] launching the processes.

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_LAUNCH to left child, src=0, dest=1.

[00:8504] posting command SMPD_LAUNCH to left child, src=0, dest=2.

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_LAUNCH result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_LAUNCH result will be handled locally

[00:8504] successfully launched process 0

[00:8504] root process launched, starting stdin redirection.

[00:8504] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[00:8504] Authorization completed.

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_INIT src=1 ctx_key=0

[00:8504] init: 0:2:09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[00:8504] Handling cmd=SMPD_LAUNCH result

[00:8504] cmd=SMPD_LAUNCH result will be handled locally

[00:8504] successfully launched process 1

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_INIT src=2 ctx_key=0

[00:8504] init: 1:2:09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_STDOUT src=1

[00:8504] Handling SMPD_STDOUT

Receive from 1

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_STDOUT src=2

[00:8504] Handling SMPD_STDOUT

Send 1 to 0 from 1

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_STDOUT src=1

[00:8504] Handling SMPD_STDOUT

Received 1

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_STDOUT src=2

[00:8504] Handling SMPD_STDOUT

Send !!

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_FINALIZE src=1 ctx_key=0

[00:8504] finalize: 0:09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_FINALIZE src=2 ctx_key=0

[00:8504] finalize: 1:09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_EXIT src=2

[00:8504] saving exit code: rank 1, exitcode 0, pg <09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c>

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_EXIT src=1

[00:8504] saving exit code: rank 0, exitcode 0, pg <09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c>

[00:8504] last process exited, tearing down the job tree num_exited=2 num_procs=2.

[00:8504] handling command SMPD_CLOSED src=1

[00:8504] closed command received from left child.

[00:8504] smpd manager successfully stopped listening.

**SMPD, rank 0:**

C:>smpd -d 3 -p 8677

[-1:26348] Launching SMPD service.

[-1:26348] smpd listening on port 8677

[-1:26348] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[-1:26348] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[-1:26348] create manager process (using smpd daemon credentials)

[-1:26348] Launching smpd as 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe" -p 8677 -d 11 -mgr 568 "job"'

[-1:26348] smpd reading the port string from the manager

[-1:21980] Launching smpd manager instance.

[-1:21980] created set for manager listener 316

[-1:21980] smpd manager listening on port 63006

[-1:26348] closing the pipe to the manager

[-1:21980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[-1:21980] Authorization completed.

[-1:21980] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[-1:21980] Received session header from parent id=1, parent=0, level=0

[01:21980] Connecting back to parent using host SYS-LT-GLH9K13 and endpoint 63004

[01:21980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[01:21980] Authorization completed.

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_CONNECT src=0

[01:21980] now connecting to 10.241.42.117

[01:21980] 1 -> 2 : returning SMPD_CONTEXT_LEFT_CHILD

[01:21980] using spn RestrictedKrbHost/10.241.42.117 to contact server

[01:21980] SYS-LT-GLH9K13 posting a re-connect to 10.241.42.117:60967 in left child context.

[01:21980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[01:21980] Authorization completed.

[01:21980] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[01:21980] 1 -> 2 : returning SMPD_CONTEXT_LEFT_CHILD

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_COLLECT src=0

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_COLLECT src=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 2 : returning left_context

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_COLLECT to left child, src=0, dest=2.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_COLLECT result

[01:21980] forward result SMPD_COLLECT to dest=0

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_STARTDBS src=0

[01:21980] sending start_dbs result command kvs = 09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c.

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_LAUNCH src=0

[01:21980] Successfully handled bcast nodeids command.

[01:21980] setting environment variable: <MPIEXEC_HOSTNAME> =

[01:21980] env: PMI_SIZE=2

[01:21980] env: PMI_KVS=09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[01:21980] env: PMI_DOMAIN=f3d4b096-ec59-4893-b18d-dc9361b19a16

[01:21980] env: PMI_HOST=localhost

[01:21980] env: PMI_PORT=2be5d33c-c22f-4bf6-88f7-e2ca3d75ecd8

[01:21980] env: PMI_SMPD_ID=1

[01:21980] env: PMI_APPNUM=0

[01:21980] env: PMI_SPAWN=0

[01:21980] env: PMI_NODE_IDS=smp_region_21980

[01:21980] env: PMI_RANK_AFFINITIES=affinity_region_21980

[01:21980] searching for 'helloMPI.exe' in workdir 'C:'

[01:21980] searching for 'helloMPI.exe' in path '\my_shared_folder\on_the_network'

[01:21980] C:>CreateProcess('\my_shared_older\on_the_network\helloMPI.exe helloMPI.exe)

[01:21980] env: PMI_RANK=0

[01:21980] env: PMI_SMPD_KEY=0

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_LAUNCH src=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 2 : returning left_context

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_LAUNCH to left child, src=0, dest=2.

[01:21980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[01:21980] Authorization completed.

[01:21980] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_INIT src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_INIT to parent, src=1, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_INIT result

[01:21980] forward SMPD_INIT result to dest=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_LAUNCH result

[01:21980] forward result SMPD_LAUNCH to dest=0

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BCPUT src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BCPUT command from smpd 1

```
    ctx_key=0

    rank=0

    value=port=63018 description="172.23.16.1 10.241.42.127 SYS-LT-GLH9K13 " shm_host=SYS-LT-GLH9K13 shm_queue=9776:580

    result=success
```

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] initializing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c): in=1 size=2

[01:21980] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 0 to 1 out of 2

[01:21980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[01:21980] Authorization completed.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_INIT src=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_INIT to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_INIT result

[01:21980] forward SMPD_INIT result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BCPUT src=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BCPUT command from smpd 2

```
    ctx_key=0

    rank=1

    value=port=60973 description="172.31.192.1 10.241.42.117 DESKTOP-OBG36E6 " shm_host=DESKTOP-OBG36E6 shm_queue=15664:568

    result=success
```

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=65535

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=65535

[01:21980] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 1 to 2 out of 2

[01:21980] all in barrier, release the barrier.

[01:21980] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[01:21980] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[01:21980] read 16 bytes from stdout

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=1, dest=0.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_STDOUT src=2

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BCGET src=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BCGET command from smpd 2

```
    ctx_key=0

    rank=0

    value=port=63018 description="172.23.16.1 10.241.42.127 SYS-LT-GLH9K13 " shm_host=SYS-LT-GLH9K13 shm_queue=9776:580

    result=success
```

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[01:21980] cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result will be handled locally

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[01:21980] forward result SMPD_STDOUT to dest=2

[01:21980] read 12 bytes from stdout

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=1, dest=0.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_STDOUT src=2

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_FINALIZE src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_FINALIZE to parent, src=1, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_FINALIZE src=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_FINALIZE to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[01:21980] cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result will be handled locally

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[01:21980] forward result SMPD_STDOUT to dest=2

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_FINALIZE result

[01:21980] forward SMPD_FINALIZE result to dest=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_FINALIZE result

[01:21980] forward SMPD_FINALIZE result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=1 ctx_key=0

[01:21980] initializing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c): in=1 size=2

[01:21980] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 0 to 1 out of 2

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=65535

[01:21980] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=65535

[01:21980] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 1 to 2 out of 2

[01:21980] all in barrier, release the barrier.

[01:21980] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[01:21980] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[01:21980] process_id=0 process refcount == 2, pmi client closed.

[01:21980] forwarding command SMPD_EXIT src=2

[01:21980] 1 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 1

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_EXIT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_EXIT result

[01:21980] forward result SMPD_EXIT to dest=2

[01:21980] reading failed, assuming stdout is closed. error 0xc000014b

[01:21980] process_id=0 process refcount == 1, stdout closed.

[01:21980] reading failed, assuming stderr is closed. error 0xc000014b

[01:21980] process_id=0 process refcount == 0, stderr closed.

[01:21980] process_id=0 rank=0 refcount=0, waiting for the process to finish exiting.

[01:21980] creating an exit command for process id=0  rank=0, pid=9776, exit code=0.

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_EXIT to parent, src=1, dest=0.

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_CLOSE from parent

[01:21980] sending close command to left child

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_EXIT result

[01:21980] cmd=SMPD_EXIT result will be handled locally

[01:21980] handling command SMPD_CLOSED src=2

[01:21980] 1 -> 2 : returning SMPD_CONTEXT_LEFT_CHILD

[01:21980] closed command received from left child.

[01:21980] sending 'closed' command to parent context

[01:21980] posting command SMPD_CLOSED to parent, src=1, dest=0.

[01:21980] Handling cmd=SMPD_CLOSED result

[01:21980] cmd=SMPD_CLOSED result will be handled locally

[01:21980] smpd manager successfully stopped listening.

[01:21980] SMPD exiting with error code 0.

**SMPD, rank 1:**

C:>smpd -d 3 -p 8677

[-1:1980] Launching SMPD service.

[-1:1980] smpd listening on port 8677

[-1:1980] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[-1:1980] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[-1:1980] create manager process (using smpd daemon credentials)

[-1:1980] Launching smpd as 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe" -p 8677 -d 11 -mgr 564 "job"'

[-1:1980] smpd reading the port string from the manager

[-1:1536] Launching smpd manager instance.

[-1:1536] created set for manager listener 332

[-1:1536] smpd manager listening on port 60967

[-1:1980] closing the pipe to the manager

[-1:1536] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[-1:1536] Authorization completed.

[-1:1536] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[-1:1536] Received session header from parent id=2, parent=1, level=1

[02:1536] Connecting back to parent using host SYS-LT-GLH9K13 and endpoint 63006

[02:1536] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[02:1536] Authorization completed.

[02:1536] handling command SMPD_COLLECT src=0

[02:1536] handling command SMPD_LAUNCH src=0

[02:1536] Successfully handled bcast nodeids command.

[02:1536] setting environment variable: <MPIEXEC_HOSTNAME> =

[02:1536] env: PMI_SIZE=2

[02:1536] env: PMI_KVS=09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c

[02:1536] env: PMI_DOMAIN=f3d4b096-ec59-4893-b18d-dc9361b19a16

[02:1536] env: PMI_HOST=localhost

[02:1536] env: PMI_PORT=0cc153c0-683c-4af5-93b2-e8aa848a8098

[02:1536] env: PMI_SMPD_ID=2

[02:1536] env: PMI_APPNUM=0

[02:1536] env: PMI_SPAWN=0

[02:1536] env: PMI_NODE_IDS=smp_region_1536

[02:1536] env: PMI_RANK_AFFINITIES=affinity_region_1536

[02:1536] searching for 'helloMPI.exe' in workdir 'C:'

[02:1536] searching for 'helloMPI.exe' in path '\my_shared_folder\on_the_network'

[02:1536] C:>CreateProcess(\my_shared_folder\on_the_network\helloMPI.exe helloMPI.exe)

[02:1536] env: PMI_RANK=1

[02:1536] env: PMI_SMPD_KEY=0

[02:1536] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client.

[02:1536] Authorization completed.

[02:1536] version check complete, using PMP version 4.

[02:1536] forwarding command SMPD_INIT src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] 2 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 2

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_INIT to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_INIT result

[02:1536] forward SMPD_INIT result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] Caching business card for rank 1

[02:1536] forwarding command SMPD_BCPUT src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] 2 -> 1 : returning parent_context: 1 < 2

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_BCPUT to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=1.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_BCPUT result

[02:1536] forward SMPD_BCPUT result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] initializing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c): in=1 size=1

[02:1536] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 0 to 1 out of 1

[02:1536] all in barrier, sending barrier to parent.

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_BARRIER to parent, src=2, ctx_key=65535, dest=1.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_BARRIER result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_BARRIER result will be handled locally

[02:1536] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[02:1536] read 20 bytes from stdout

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[02:1536] forwarding command SMPD_BCGET src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] 2 -> 1 : returning parent_context: 1 < 2

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_BCGET to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=1.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_BCGET result

[02:1536] forward SMPD_BCGET result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] Caching business card for rank 0

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result will be handled locally

[02:1536] read 9 bytes from stdout

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_STDOUT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[02:1536] forwarding command SMPD_FINALIZE src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] 2 -> 0 : returning parent_context: 0 < 2

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_FINALIZE to parent, src=2, ctx_key=0, dest=0.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_STDOUT result will be handled locally

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_FINALIZE result

[02:1536] forward SMPD_FINALIZE result to dest=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] handling command SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] Handling SMPD_BARRIER src=2 ctx_key=0

[02:1536] initializing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c): in=1 size=1

[02:1536] incrementing barrier(09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c) incount from 0 to 1 out of 1

[02:1536] all in barrier, sending barrier to parent.

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_BARRIER to parent, src=2, ctx_key=65535, dest=1.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_BARRIER result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_BARRIER result will be handled locally

[02:1536] sending reply to barrier command '09d0a7d8-90da-44cc-8d8c-db607d6bc52c'.

[02:1536] process_id=0 process refcount == 2, pmi client closed.

[02:1536] reading failed, assuming stdout is closed. error 0xc000014b

[02:1536] process_id=0 process refcount == 1, stdout closed.

[02:1536] reading failed, assuming stderr is closed. error 0xc000014b

[02:1536] process_id=0 process refcount == 0, stderr closed.

[02:1536] process_id=0 rank=1 refcount=0, waiting for the process to finish exiting.

[02:1536] creating an exit command for process id=0  rank=1, pid=15664, exit code=0.

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_EXIT to parent, src=2, dest=0.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_EXIT result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_EXIT result will be handled locally

[02:1536] handling command SMPD_CLOSE from parent

[02:1536] sending 'closed' command to parent context

[02:1536] posting command SMPD_CLOSED to parent, src=2, dest=1.

[02:1536] Handling cmd=SMPD_CLOSED result

[02:1536] cmd=SMPD_CLOSED result will be handled locally

[02:1536] smpd manager successfully stopped listening.

[02:1536] SMPD exiting with error code 0.

Comment: This kind of delays can be caused by (reverse) DNS not working correctly (program goes through after a timeout), or the host having non usable IP interfaces (program chooses an other interfance after a timeout), so these are the two things I would start checking.

Comment: Probably add a "Windows" tag to this question, because this has nothing to do with MPI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these comments. I am new to using MPI and not confident enough myself to assume that this is likely to be a network issue, and not some basic misuse of the library. I will start checking network issues as suggested.